# Multithreading observablecollection

Tags: authentication, parallel-processing, webclient

I have an `ObservableCollection` like this:

```
 private string Username;
 private string Password;

 ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
 employees.Add(new Employee() { Username = "Bill54", Password = "sundayfunday"});
 employees.Add(new Employee() { Username = "Sarah66", Password = "doglover"});
 employees.Add(new Employee() { Username = "Nick42", Password = "gopatriots"});
 return employees;
```

and I want each item to do this through `Parallel.ForEach` using its string values like:

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebclient)
{             
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values.Add("username", Username);
    values.Add("login_password", Password);
    var responseString = client.UploadValues(url, values);
}
```

How can I do this?